# how to replace a component by an other component without having to refresh React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class linkNav extends Component
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
    }
}

widthUpdate = () =>
{
   if(this.state.width > 700)
   {
       this.setState(prevState => (
           {  
                width: window.innerWidth
           }
       ))
   }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.widthUpdate(), 10);
}
render()
{
     if(this.state.width > 700)
    {
        return(
            <Navbar
            logo = { Logo } 
            home = { home_icon }
            aboutme = { aboutme_icon }
            skill = { skill_icon }
            project = { project_icon }
            contact = { contact_icon }
            />
        )
    }
    else
    {
        return(
            <Responsivebar/>
        )
    }
}
}

export default linkNav;
```

Hello as you saw in the title and in the code my goal is to change the component according to the size of window without refresh but it does not work unfortunately. :(

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Note: `linkNav` should be `LinkNav`

Comment: `state.windowWidth` isn't going to update itself.  You need to make that happen, most likely by listening to the `resize` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Comment: Your code works for me without refreshing, but it doesn't change back to the NavBar. Here's my take: Here's how to do this properly: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5y0ol5kkp

Comment: What's the meaning of "refresh react.js"?

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks a lot it's works !!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an event Listener! 
Make sure you stop the event listener on unmount.

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.setState({ width: Window.innerwidth }) 
    })
```